# How to retrieve which child was selected

Tags: jquery, html

I need to tell which child was clicked on so I can change the background color of that specific line.

```
<script>
         var counter = 0;
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".eastern > ul").click(function(){
                counter++;
                $(".northern > ul").append("<li>Champlain " + counter.toString() + "</li>");
            });
            $(".northern > ul").click(function(){
                $(".northern > ul").children(':nth-child(n)').css("background-color","blue");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: `counter.toString()` is unnecessary.  Javascript does not have variable types and it will actually merge this with the string automatically when you do `+ integer + 'string'`

Answer (score 2):

Pass in `event` to your function, then use

```
$(event.target).addClass("yourClass");
```

Demo using `ul` : http://jsfiddle.net/WS7VK/

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` will be the object that caused the event inside the event handler (see comments added to your script).

```
<script>
     var counter = 0;
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".eastern > ul").click(function(){
            // the this pointer here contains the object that was clicked on
            counter++;
            $(".northern > ul").append("<li>Champlain " + counter.toString() + "</li>");
        });
        $(".northern > ul").click(function(){
            // the this pointer here contains the object that was clicked on
            $(".northern > ul").children(':nth-child(n)').css("background-color","blue");
        });
    });
</script>
```

So, if you want to change the color of only the clicked on child objects, you could do that like this:

```
<script>
     var counter = 0;
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".eastern > ul").click(function(){
            // the this pointer here contains the object that was clicked on
            counter++;
            $(".northern > ul").append("<li>Champlain " + counter.toString() + "</li>");
        });
        $(".northern > ul").click(function(){
            // set color of children of the clicked-on object
            $(this).children().css("background-color","blue");
        });
    });
</script>
```